# Best way to export data from on cosmos db account into another

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

What i want to do is similar to what we can easily do with `Azure Sql Server databases`, where we can click on the copy functionality what create the same database in another Sql Server.

I don't see that functionality in `Azure Cosmos DB` resource.

Looking in the Microsoft documentation they seem to point into a [Data migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLSource)
but if we already have many containers/collections and millions of records, running this locally might be impractical.

Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: There is an official guide with migration options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/migration-choices

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure data factory pipeline to move data from one azure cosmos container to another container.
Here are the steps I have followed to move data from one container to another using ADF.

1. I have two containers in Cosmos db as shown below,
   [image]
2. Employee container has data,
   [image]
3. Initially staff1 has no data,
   [image]
4. Created an Azure data factory resource.
5. Created Linked service of type **Azure cosmos DB**.
   [image]
6. Created two data sets of type **Azure cosmos DB**. One is for source, and another is for sink.
   [image]
   [image]
7. Created a pipeline as shown below,
   [image]
8. Selected Sink as shown below,
   [image]
9. Ran pipeline run successfully, and data is inserted into target container.
   [image]
   [image]
10. Data is inserted into target as shown below,
    [image]
    Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=data-factory#managed-identity)